# python error NameError name is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

```
class Bird :

    '''A base class to define bird properties.'''

    count = 0
    def_init_( self , chat ) 
    self.sound = chat
    Bird.count += 1
    def talk( self ) :
    return self.sound
```

`NameError: name 'def_init_' is not defined`

I tried using 2 underscores on both side of the 'init'

Comment: `def_init_` is not a function or variable. Fix it (however is appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple typo. You're missing the space after `def` - it should be:

```
def __init__(self, chat):
```

Comment: And missing the `:` and indent ..

Comment: Yeah, the indentation is pretty badly wrong in the above code. I'm never sure how much of that is real and how much is copy/paste error, though.

Answer (score 1):

you had lots of error in your script actually 
    1> indentation
    2> give space after def 
    3> colon after def **init**( self , chat )
       follow the rules then everything will be okay....

```
class Bird :

    '''A base class to define bird properties.'''

    count = 0
    def __init__( self , chat ): 
        self.sound = chat
        Bird.count += 1

    def talk( self ):
        return self.sound
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `_init_` function to `def __init__(self, chat):`.

The `__` is called a *dunder*, which is short for 'double underscore'. We usually use this, magic methods like instantiation. So for example, `[]` would be called `__get__`.

Whenever you see a *dunder*, you know it has a special use.